# Retrieving results from background Gearman job/task

Tags: php, symfony, gearman

Subject is quite self-explanatory, but I definitely need a fresh pair of eyes on this.

I am using `mmoreram/GearmanBundle` `Symfony2` bundle to send jobs to execute. So, far I have managed to send a job, execute it and return results. That part works as expected.

However, I am trying to the same with background job/tasks. I know that, in this scenario, client does not wait for job to complete, but I was hoping that job handle can help me with that (e.g. retrieve job status).

```
$gearman = $this->get('gearman');
$jobId = $gearman->doHighBackgroundJob("CsvWorker~parseCsv", json_encode(["foo", "bar", "123"]));
sleep(3);

// At this point, job has completed for sure (it's very simple)
var_dump($jobId);
var_dump($gearman->getJobStatus($jobId));
```

This outputs the following:

```
string 'H:localhost.localdomain:10' (length=26)

object(Mmoreram\GearmanBundle\Module\JobStatus)[410]
  private 'known' => boolean false
  private 'running' => boolean false
  private 'completed' => int 0
  private 'completionTotal' => int 0
```

The `known => false`, in particular,  really puzzles me. During the job execution, I made sure to invoke correctly `sendStatus` and `sendComplete` methods.

So, I guess, a general question would be: once the job has completed, is it **still known** to `Gearman`?

**UPDATE:**

I managed to add some code changes to the bundle which allowed me to listen for data being returned by job. That way, I may be able to persist that in database, however, my client (job creator) is still pretty much left in the dark on whether the job has actually finished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/gearmanclient.jobstatus.php), as long as the job is known to the server, it is not completed.

Answer (score 2):

I found  [here](http://william.shallum.net/random-notes/usingmemcachetogetresultsfromagearmanbackgroundjob) such an option for solving the problem.

It is convenient when you need to complete a task, and the answer is needed only for a while.

Worker

```
$gmworker = new GearmanWorker(); 
$gmworker->addServer(); 
$gmworker->addFunction("long_running_task", "long_running_task_fn"); 


print "Waiting for job...\n"; 
while($gmworker->work()) { 
    if ($gmworker->returnCode() != GEARMAN_SUCCESS) { 
      echo "return_code: " . $gmworker->returnCode() . "\n"; 
      break; 
    } 
} 


function long_running_task_fn($job) { 
    $mc = memcache_connect('localhost', 11211); 
    $result = 1; 
    $n = $job->workload(); 
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $n; $i++) { 
        $result *= $i; 
        $job->sendStatus($i, $n); 
        sleep(1); 
    } 
    memcache_set($mc, $job->handle(), $result); 
}
```

Client

```
<?php

if ($_POST['start']) {
        $gmc = new GearmanClient();
        $gmc->addServer();
        $handle = $gmc->doBackground('long_running_task', '10');
        header('Location: /client.php?handle='.urlencode($handle));
}

if ($_GET['handle']) {
        $handle = $_GET['handle'];
        $gmc = new GearmanClient();
        $gmc->addServer();
        $status = $gmc->jobStatus($handle);
}

function get_result($handle) {
        $mc = memcache_connect('localhost', 11211);
        $reply = memcache_get($mc, $handle);
        memcache_close($mc);
        return $reply;
}

?>
```